# Learning the exponents in a sum of two modular roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
Suppose that $n$ is a large and known integer (say, with 100 digits) and that you are given access to a function

$$f(x) = x^a + x^b$$

with unknown exponents $a,b \in \Z/n$.  You are allowed to evaluate $f$ on any cyclic ring $\Z/q$ with a solution to $x^n = 1$, where $x$ and $q$ are of your choosing as long as $\gcd(n,q) = 1$.  You are allowed several evaluations with distinct $x$ and $q$.  For simplicity you can assume that $q$ is a product of primes (which may not be distinct) that are all 1 mod $n$ and that $x$ is an $n$th root of unity, since for instance $n$ could be prime.  Linnik's effective version of Dirichlet's theorem says that there is a ready supply of values of $q$.

My ultimate question:  What algorithms in number theory are available to find the exponents $a$ and $b$?   Of course you can find them in principle with one enormous value of $q$.  The question is what is known about efficiency as a function of $d$, the number of digits of $n$.  The problem is like discrete logarithm, but more complicated because there are two terms.

I am also interested in this more tangible question: Can you find a moderate value of $q$ such that $f$ is injective?  Heuristically, $O(d)$ digits should be enough.  I am thinking that GRH implies that $f$ is strictly injective for most values of $q$ with $O(d)$ digits --- is this true?  Can you prove unconditionally $f$ that is usually injective in this range, or usually mostly injective?

Comment: I think you're allowing enough information to evaluate $f$ at any $n$-th root of unity in any ring at all. Methods for finding $a,b$ are probably easier to first work out for $\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_m]$ with $m \mid n$ before worrying about finite fields.

Comment: Yes, that's the point.  The crux of the matter is computational complexity.  $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is clearly impractical in the terms of this question, hence I consider finite quotients.

Comment: Okay, it's not obvious why it's impractical.  The reason is that $f$ may not be computed directly in the form given; it may just equal the right side.  It may have a much more complicated formula that renders calculation in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ impractical.

Comment: If $n \mid p-1$, then $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_p$, and the restriction to evaluating in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$ allows us to get an arbitrary amount of $p$-adic precision. This approach should actually work if the goal was to find $f(\zeta_n)$; but the point I wanted to make is that an approach for $\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is probably easier to find (and surely much easier to analyze), and once you have it, can then work out how to do a practical computation with finite quotients.

Comment: If you were allowed direct access to $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$, or even more clearly to $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/n]$, then the problem would be easy. Indeed, $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_p$.  But how much $p$-adic precision is necessary for the question?

Comment: Easy with a sparse polynomial representation, but is it actually easy with a black box representation of elements of the field?

Comment: Take the problem this way:  $n$ has 100 digits.  Every time you call $f$, you are charged one hundredth of one cent for every digit of $q$.   You are also charged for electricity for use of your own computer.  What do you do?

Comment: Ah, if $n$ is odd, it easy to find $a+b$, by computing $$ f(1+n) \equiv 2 + (a+b)n \pmod{n^2} $$

Comment: I thought of that.  Unfortunately, $n^2$ is not coprime to $n$.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. :(

Comment: $f$ should not be injective if $q>n^4$ is prime, as the curve $(f(x)-f(y))/(x-y) = 0$ will have points in $\mathbb{F}_q$ by Weil.

Comment: Thanks, Felipe, but it's actually a zero-dimensional variety rather than a curve because you also have $x^n = y^n = 1$.

Comment: Arguing about dimension is a bit of a red herring. But I have to take care of the condition of being $n$-th roots of unity, which I forgot. I consider $f(x^m)-f(y^m)/(x^m-y^m)=0, m=(q-1)/n$. Now, I have to be careful with the degree,which is $m\max(a,b)$. If that's smaller than $q^{1/4}$, I can use Weil. So $f$ shouldn't be injective if $a,b$ are small.

Comment: If $m < q^{1/4}$, then $q$ has at most 4/3 as many digits as $n$.

Comment: Think about it.  If $q > n^3$, then you expect all $n$ values of $f$ to be distinct.  The Weil estimate is generally in the ballpark of heuristic counting.

Comment: This is a very preliminary thought, please let me know if it makes any sense: Suppose $n || q - 1$, and write $x^a+ x^b = x^a(1 + x^{b-a})$. The value $x^a$ is always an n-th root of unity, where as $1 + x^{b-a}$ is very likely to have its order coprime to n. Then one can actually extract the values $x^a$ and $1 + x^{b-a}$ from each evaluation.

Comment: @Hao: As an extreme counterexample, suppose $q$ is prime and $n = q-1$. Then $1 + x^{b-a}$ is *never* going to have order coprime to $n$. Still, there may be something one can do with $(1+x^{b-a})^n$ and suitable $q$.

Comment: You *can* find $a+b$ (if you can compute discrete logarithms), because $f(x)^2 - f(x^2) = 2 x^{a+b}$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: thanks for pointing it out! I was assuming that $n$ is also a prime, as the author suggests in another comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can compute discrete logarithms, there's an easy solution:

$$ f(\zeta) = \zeta^a + \zeta^b $$
$$ f(\zeta^2) = (\zeta^a)^2 + (\zeta^b)^2 $$

is a system of two equations in the quantities $\zeta^a$ and $\zeta^b$, allowing you to solve for $(\zeta^a, \zeta^b)$. There will be 2 solutions, but that just reflects the symmetry between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Duh, I think you're right, this works.  I'm not entirely sure why I missed it, other than that I was moving too quickly.  I actually had a different question at first that I simplified to this one with a similar trick.

Comment: At least if you fix q, then problem cannot be any easier than discrete logarithm.   If you know b, then it simply is the discrete logarithm problem.

Comment: If you could send me your name by private e-mail, I'd be more than happy to thank you for this, even though you just basically caught me in a mistake.

Comment: @GregKuperberg anything came out of this?

Comment: Yes, this paper on lens spaces:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02887

Answer (score 1):

To get things started, a straightforward algorithm is to use $\mathbb{Z} / (2^n - 1)$, and read $a$ and $b$ off of the only two bits set in the smallest positive representative of $f(2)$.

Of course, this is a very large modulus — but if $n$ factors as a product of small prime powers $q$, then we can use this method for $\mathbb{Z} / (2^q - 1)$ to obtain $a \bmod q$ and $b \bmod q$. (if a single digit is set, then $a \equiv b \bmod q$ and you can still obtain it)

Then for each pair of prime powers $q$ and $q'$, you know the sets $\{ a \bmod q, b \bmod q \}$ and $\{ a \bmod q', b \bmod q' \}$, and you have to figure out which elements of each pair go with each other. This can be done by using the same method to find $\{ a \bmod (qq'), b \bmod (qq') \}$.

Once you know which classes go together, the Chinese Remainder Theorem lets you reassemble $a \bmod n$ and $b \bmod n$.

---

Naturally, if you have a better algorithm for the mod-$q$ residues of $a$ and $b$, you could use the same high level algorithm described above, but with using the better algorithm in place of the stated one.

Comment: I agree that the question is easy if $n$ factors into small prime powers.  This is not the difficult end of the question, but it is a useful remark.  What if $n$ is prime?